# Can't update a certain field Laravel Elequent

Tags: laravel

#### In the controller update method, I can update this field with no problem:

```
public function updateLecture($id){
    $subject = Subject::findOrFail($id);
    $subject->name = request('name');
    $subject->save();
}
```

---

But when I do try to update the description:

```
$subjet->description = request('description');
```

It gives me this  **error** :

> 'Creating default object from empty value'

and I know for certain that the `request('description')` is not empty.

Comment: Show Subject `$fillable` property

Comment: I have set a $guarded = []; on it. @Davit

Comment: Can you show $guarded property?

Comment: `protected $guarded = []; <br>` 
I'm just testing it so it's an empty array meaning it should accept anything Davit

Comment: for testing try this code ` $subjet->description = 'test';`

Comment: Is it because your working example has `$subject` but your non-working example has `$subjet` with a misspelling?

Comment: $fillable is for mass assignment only @Davit

Comment: It was a case of misspelling indeed, I have come from compliers that go crazy when you do something like that but I'm new to laravel development so I have to be more careful and try not to waste others times.
Thanks all. 
@JoelHinz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did spelling mistake,

```
$subject->description = request('description'); // make subjet to subject
```